# Main with single argument

Tags: c, c89

I've recently come across a C program in which the main function only took a single argument. Is this legal in C89? gcc didn't seem to have any problems with it.

What I *think* happens is that the signature is ignored and main is called as `main(int,char**)` anyways, but I'm not sure.

It looks like this in the program:
`main(argc) {
...
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C89 standard, it is not legal. From section *2.1.2.2 Hosted environment*:

```
The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation
declares no prototype for this function. It can be defined with no parameters:

    int main(void) { /*...*/ }

or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv , though any names
may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*...*/ }
```

The C99 standard states the same in section *5.1.2.2.1 Program startup*.

Comment: The standard is all fine and dandy, but I think what really matters is does it work for the compiler he's targeting? Does anyone here have a compiler where the above code DOESN'T work?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I agree with you. However, the OP did explictly ask _Is this legal C89_? FWIW, Microsoft compilers VC9 and VC10 compiled fine.

Comment: Nope, you were right, that was the question. I already knew it worked, I just didn't know if it was legal.

Comment: You left off the last bit from that section - "or in some other implementation-defined manner."  An implementation is free to define `main` in a manner other than what's specified in the standard *as long as it documents the additional signature(s)*.  Having said that, I see nothing in the GCC manual that indicates this is a legal signature, so the behavior is *undefined*, so there's no requirement for the compiler to issue a diagnostic for it.  Also, we're assuming this code is meant for a **hosted** implementation; if it's meant for a freestanding implementation, then all bets are off.

Comment: @JohnBode, I don't see that in the C89 standard, but I do see it in the C99 standard but there it is qualified with _Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as char ** argv, and so on_. It does not state that an implementation is free to change the signature.

Comment: @hmjd In what I have, it's: "or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-deﬁned manner." where `9)` is the footnote you quoted. The same in n1570. So however it was meant, one _can_ read the part after the semicolon as separate from the "or equivalent" with the footnote. I wish they had been more unambiguous.

Comment: @hmjd - it was added in C99.  And that footnote applies to the second standard definition `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works[<sup>†</sup>](http://ideone.com/ZjjfO), but it is useless.

Remember that in C, any variable that doesn't have a type specified defaults to `int`, so that means that the function expands to this:

```
int main(int argc) {
    ...
}
```

Which is legal in C89. Most of the time, however, if you want to know the number of arguments sent to a program, you probably want the contents of those arguments, so this is mostly useless.

However, GCC (when compiled with `-Wall`) gives me a warning:

```
Only one parameter on 'main' declaration.
```

It's just saying that this code is pretty much useless.

However, technically, as @hmjd noted, this is ***illegal***, in that it is undefined behavior. However, in most implementations of C that I have came across, when you pass extra parameters to a function, they are just ignored for the most part. So, unless you are on a system where it matters if you overflow the amount of variables sent to a function, you should be fine.

Comment: I think the phrasing matters here, the code may *compile* with GCC and several others compilers, but it is not *legal* according to the C89 standard.

Comment: This was used in an obscured C program. I knew it worked (kinda), I was more interested in knowing whether that was actually defined behavior (I personally think that using illegal code in obscured programs is cheating).

Comment: The behavior is ***undefined***; the code is erroneous, but the compiler is under no obligation to do anything in particular about it.  It may halt translation and issue a diagnostic, or it may translate the code without any diagnostics, or anything in between.  I interpret ***illegal*** to mean that the compiler *must* issue a diagnostic and cease translation, which is not the case here.