# `int main(i){ printf("i = %d\n", i); }` i value is 1. why ? please explain?

Tags: c, initialization, implicit

Why it prints I value as 1, can someone please explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(i)
{ 
    printf("i = %d\n", i); 
}
```

output i = 1.

Comment: You have not initialized `i`, so it will print a random (undefined) value.

Comment: First argument to `main` function is `argc`, so your `i` shows "1 argument passed" from command line. When application is run, 1st argument is a path to executable containing the `main` function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3024197/6352710. If you declare second argument, you'll be able to print the path.

Comment: It's not undefined at all: main will be passed the number of command line arguments and a list of them. The first argument is the command name itself, so argv (or in this case i) will be 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C` is interpreting `i` as type `int` - [if you don't declare a variable, its default type is `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11064331/7431860). By coincidence, `main` is used to being called as `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, so your `i` (which is now an `int`) fits into that first parameter. `main` will allow you to call it with only one argument, [but this is technically undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262705/7431860) - don't do it.

The first value, `argc`, is a number detailing how many command line arguments were given. (The second is the strings of those arguments.) In your case, only one command-line argument was given, that being the name of the executable (probably `./a.out`).

Try running your code with `./a.out some strings here` - you'll notice different values printing.

Comment: I don't think the implicit type has anything to do with the way `main()` is normally called. This is an old-style function definition, where types aren't specified in the parameter list. And the default type of undeclared variables is `int`.

Comment: @Barmar I did not know that, I assumed it was converting it - I'll look for a reference for that behavior and link it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two or three different little mysteries here.  Not sure which one you're wondering about, so I guess I'll answer all three.

- How did you get away with declaring `int main(i)` without a type for `i`?
- How did you get away with declaring `main` as accepting one parameter, not the conventional two?
- Where did the value 1 come from when you ran it?

Answers:

(1) Once upon a time, a rather long time ago by now, in what pretty much counts as the dawn (or at least the morning) of C, the function definition syntax was different.  You didn't say things like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
}
```

Instead, you said

```
int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    ...
}
```

And that was when "implicit `int`" was all the rage, too.  So if you just wrote

```
int main(argc, argv)
char *argv[];
{
    ...
}
```

the compiler said "Okay, there's a parameter `argv` and it's a `char **`, and there's a parameter `argc` and it's a... oh, you didn't say, so I'll just quietly assume `int`."

And since C has always been pretty big on backwards compatibility, many compilers are still accepting the older syntax today, even though it's been officially obsolete for a while now.

(2) Also, in your case you completely left off the `argv` part.  `main` is supposed to have two arguments, that's the way the system is calling it when your program starts up, but you only declared it as accepting one.  So why did it work?

Strictly speaking the behavior is undefined when a function gets called with a different number of arguments than it expects, but it's the kind of thing you can often get away with, especially in the case that there were more arguments passed than expected.  So although the system passed a second, `argv` argument that your program didn't expect, the extra argument was just quietly discarded.

(3) And then, where did the 1 come from?  Well, that's due to what `main`'s conventional `argc` and `argv` arguments actually mean.  C's `main` definition is based on the command-line invocation.  Normally people type things like

```
programname somefilename someotherargument
```

and then hit RETURN.  This invokes a program named `programname`, with two command-line arguments `somefilename` and `someotherargument`.  So how are those passed in to `main`?

Well, `argc` is a count of how many of them there were, and `argv` is an array (v is for "vector") of the argument strings themselves.  And the argument list always includes the program name itself.  So if you invoke

```
programname somefilename someotherargument
```

then `argc` comes in as 3 and `argv` comes in as the array

```
{ "programname", "somefilename", "someotherargument", NULL }
```

But if you invoke something with no arguments, then `argc` still comes in as 1.  So that's where the 1 you saw came from.